# Pass value generated from jQuery to PHP Mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

This seems simple, but I can't find a solution. I created an HTML form that uses a little bit of jQuery to generate a value (total price) based on user selections in dropdown menus. I'm trying to get that generated value to show up in the email that is being sent via PHP Mail. All other values from my form are showing up, but I can't seem to get that value at all. I'm using the POST method.

Here's the HTML (this is just a small portion showing the part I need. This displays the value to the screen, based on what the user chooses in the drop down menu):

```
<form name="quote" id="price-quote" action="mail.php" method="post">    
  <label class="control-label" for="carpet_cleaning">Bedrooms</label><br>
    <select class="form-control-1" id="carpet_cleaning" name ="bedrooms_selection">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

<!--displays the total price to the screen-->
 <div class="total-price">
    <h2>Total Price: <span id="output1" name="total_price"></h2>
 </div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$("#carpet_cleaning").change(function (){
  var bedrooms = $("#carpet_cleaning").val();
  var total = (bedrooms * 10);
  var totalPrice = "$" + total;
  $("#output1").text(totalPrice).fadeIn();
});
</script>
```

Super simple JS Fiddle for a better visual https://jsfiddle.net/b7tyx7uk/

So here's the PHP code I have that will send the email

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['bedrooms_selection'])){
  $services[]=' Bedrooms: '.$_POST['bedrooms_selection'];
}
$totalPrice = $_POST['total_price'];
 if($services){
 $email_subject = "Price Quote";
 $to = "jondoe@example.com";
 $email_body="Services Needed: \n" .implode("\n",$services) . "\n\nTotal Price: $totalPrice";
 $headers = "From: janedoe@example.com";
 mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
 header("Location: http://example.com");
}
?>
```

It's working with all user inputs (not displayed in this post), but I can't display the total price that is generated from the jQuery. Am I overlooking something? I thought I could just give it a name and then use that name to create a new variable in the PHP, but it's not pulling that value at all. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you'd need to write `total_price` into a (hidden) input to be submitted with the form. You can do that just where you write it into `#output`

Comment: You need an input in the form for the total. Text elements don't get submitted

Comment: you're right, but it's still possible to use `.text()` to extract the content of a div and use it -> ie: `var grdTotal = $('#output1').text(); alert(grdTotal);` I strongly agree with @Barmar `you probably should calculate the price on the server` though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms don't send the contents of DIVs to the server, only the values of inputs. Add a hidden input.

```
<form name="quote" id="price-quote" action="mail.php" method="post">    
  <label class="control-label" for="carpet_cleaning">Bedrooms</label><br>
    <select class="form-control-1" id="carpet_cleaning" name ="bedrooms_selection">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

<!--displays the total price to the screen-->
 <div class="total-price">
    <h2>Total Price: <span id="output1" name="total_price"></h2>
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" id="total_price">
</form>

<script>
$("#carpet_cleaning").change(function (){
  var bedrooms = $("#carpet_cleaning").val();
  var total = (bedrooms * 10);
  var totalPrice = "$" + total;
  $("#output1").text(totalPrice).fadeIn();
  $("#total_price").val(totalPrice);
});
</script>
```

That said, you probably should calculate the price on the server. Otherwise, the user could manipulate the price using the browser console.

Comment: Yeah, that's a really good point. So I guess I'd have to do that with PHP, correct? Or do you know of an easy alternative using the same method I was using with the jQuery? I'm a front-end guy with minimal back-end experience.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything in the front-end if you don't want the user to be able to tamper with it.

Comment: For sure, that makes sense. Total beginner question here, but would the best way to do that just with PHP in my mail.php file? Or is there an easier way? I have minimal PHP knowledge, just enough to get by. In other words, I rely way too heavily on jQuery lol

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. `$total_price = $_POST['bedrooms_selection'] * 10;`

Comment: Oh that's not too bad. So I could leave the jQuery on the front end so the user could see their price, but then just do the actual math on the server, and send THAT value to the email, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct. Front-end calculations should be for convenience, back-end should be for security.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141911/discussion-between-coltvant-and-barmar).

Comment: It's just like input validation. You can use front-end validation to give immediate feedback, but you still have to validate on the back-end as well.